# search column by dictionary key and replace by dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary d={nam:name, lin:link}

I have a data frame that has below column names:

nam1 nam2 nam3 nam_4 nam_5 lin1 lin2

how do I replace the column names of dataframe with dictionary values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), so first convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nam1', 'nam2', 'nam3', 'nam_4', 'nam_5', 'lin1', 'lin2'])
d={'nam':'name', 'lin':'link'}


df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name1, name2, name3, name_4, name_5, link1, link2]
Index: []
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nam1', 'nam2', 'nam3', 'nam_4', 'nam_5', 'lin1', 'A'])
d={'nam':'name', 'lin':'link'}


s = df.columns.to_series()
pat = "(" + '|'.join(d.keys()) + ")"
df.columns = s.str.extract(pat, expand=False).combine_first(s).replace(d)
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, name, name, name, name, link, A]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you! but how do I also remove the numbers while replacing. it is alright to have duplicate columns. I want my output as name,name,name,name,link,link